Access Redis memory store mutliple VPCs
Resources
Redis - Managed service (Memory store) - Only single Auth network can connect not multiple VPC
VPC - 1 - 192.168.0.0/24
VPC - 2 - 10.0.0.0/24
Redis <-> VPC 1 (Connected to Redis Private VPC Peering)
VPC 2 - GKE cluster Auto Pilot POD
Redis - VPC 1 - VPC 2
Retirement is to connect from VPC 2 GKE Autopilot to Redis Instance through VPC 1 (as it’s authorised network)
Points to Note

Can’t peer VPC 1 & VPC 2 using VPC Peering as want to keep service
Separate No shared VPC service separation
No Hub-spoke as VPC got created and only 2 there making it more simpler

Options in mind

Twemproxy in VPC-1 with Internal Load balancer however how to connect to Internal LB from VPC 2 without peering ?
VPN tunnel considering using limited IP range
Custom VM gateway routing with IP Table

Please suggest if there is any better option available to connect from GKE autopilot in VPC 2 to Redis through VPC 1 without Peering.
Thanks

In your case, the simplest way this can be achieved is to create internal LB that requires peering. You can limit network connectivity of different VPCs by configuring the firewall rules and route tables. See this guide for steps to setup.
